# Why "on the house" not "in the house", in "have a dessert on the house"

Tags: prepositions

I thought it was a typo but said I should check it on Google, and here you go!

> My husband ordered the snapper special grilled and thought it was very
>   good. The garlic cheddar mashed potatoes are also very good.
>
> Once we were done, our waiter came over and told us that since we had
>   to wait so long for our food that we could **have a dessert on the
>   house** so we got the key lime pie which was good. Overall, we would
>   return.

I am confused. Is it an idiom? Why "on the house"?

Source: from a comment in a review entitled [“Great Food and Atmosphere”](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g48995-d1067361-r173083809-The_Boundary_House_Restaurant-Calabash_North_Carolina.html)

Comment: It's ***on*** rather than ***in*** because the idiomatic usage is nothing to do with physical location (for which contexts ***in*** is more common in general). It's more a matter of ***on** whose shoulders does the burden of cost fall?*, or ***on** whose bill does that cost appear?*. Also commonly appears as, for example, *"Let's have another drink! This one's **on** me!"*.

Comment: Thanks, but then again, can I say: "have a lunch on the house?"
P.S. never had problems with ".. on me", I use the same thing in my language.

Comment: You certainly can! Note that *on the house* effectively combines *two* idiomatic usages - where ***on X*** means *cost to be borne by X*, and ***the house*** means *the commercial establishment currently providing your food / drink / entertainment*.

Comment: I get it now! You know what, I see that my problem was with the word "**house**"! It just means the business in this context! Everything else is clear. Thank you once again.

Comment: The Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary v.3 says: **on the house** means: If you have something on the house, it is given to you free by a business. Ex: "*All the drinks were on the house.*"

Comment: If I knew that "on" had to do with cost, I would've looked the phrase up properly.

Comment: In the circumstances, I think I'd better combine those two comments into an answer. To a considerable extent, idiomatic use of prepositions is just that - *idiomatic*, not necessarily justifiable by appeals to logic or semantics. But in this particular case it seems it's the "two idioms in one" aspect that made things difficult for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [**on the house**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/on-the-house) (Cambridge dictionaries online)
>    *If you have something on the house, it is given to you free by a business*

---

It's ***on*** rather than ***in*** because the idiomatic usage is nothing to do with physical location (for which contexts ***in*** is more common in general). It's more a matter of ***on*** whose shoulders does the burden of cost fall?, or ***on*** whose bill does that cost appear?. The usage also commonly appears in forms like...

> *"Let's have another drink! This one's on me!".* (i.e. - I will pay for it)

OP's *on the house* effectively combines *two* idiomatic usages - where ***on X*** means *cost to be borne by X*, and ***the house*** is *the commercial establishment currently providing your food / drink / entertainment.*

---

Note this closely-related idiomatic usage where the choice of preposition is rather less fixed...

> *They live **on/off** State benefits* (US: *on/off welfare*)

Both AmE and BrE favour ***on*** in the above, but ***off*** is also quite common. Some native speakers may always use one or the other preposition in such constructions, and some may see them as synonymously interchangeable. But to me at least, ***on*** there carries more "neutral" implications of *a low level of income*, whereas ***off*** is a more "loaded" usage (implying criticism of people who can't/won't [fend for themselves](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fend_for_oneself)).

Comment: +1 A new expression learned: "fend for themselves". I think I understand everything written quite well. I just want to know why off has that negative connotation. You are a native speaker you may know why, but would you explain that to someone who is not, please? May be by examples where off has that negative loaded meanings?

Comment: @learner: Being a native speaker, I hadn't even noticed that I'd used another potentially unfamiliar usage there. If you grasped the meaning *from context* that's excellent (I think  it's much better to learn from context rather than by looking things up in dictionaries). It's probably "over-analysis" to seek to explain *why* using ***off*** in my example carries more negative implications. It's not so much a matter of the inherent meanings of the words - just that when two possible *meanings* exist, usage will tend to create a distinction if there are also two possible *phrasings.*

Comment: Or even "off of" in US English.

Comment: @David: I expect I use ***off of*** myself now and again - it doesn't seem particularly weird until I stop to think about it. A bit like *"The thing is, is that [blah blah]"* (I know there's a different *reason* for the latter, but they both involve "minimal effort repetition" that has a useful "emphasising" role).

Comment: I think your answer would be improved if you'd start with the full meaning of 'on the house'. I.e., start with *"A drink on the house" means "A drink that was given away by the establishment (restaurant, hotel, etc)"*